# Breaking the string into parts in C

Tags: c, regex

Its been long since I wrote a program in C language I have a string like the one below

```
"VRUWFB02=I.V.R, W.F.B, plan 2, VRUWFB01=I.V.R, W.F.B, plan 1, assa=784617896.9649164, plan24, massmedua=plan12, masspedia=IVR, masojh, jhsfdkl, oijhojomn, oiafofvj, plan"
```

and I need to get the ones before "=" i.e VRUWFB02, VRUWFB01, assa, massmedua, masspedia.

I am able to break the string but am not able to extract those specific words.

Can any one help me with this

```
char st[] = "VRUWFB02=I.V.R, W.F.B, plan 2, VRUWFB01=I.V.R, W.F.B, plan 1,assa=784617896.9649164, plan24, massmedua=plan12, masspedia=IVR, masojh, jhsfdkl, oijhojomn, oiafofvj, plan";
char *ch;
regex_t compiled;
char pattern[80] = "  ";
printf("Split \"%s\"\n", st);
ch = strtok(st, " ");
while (ch != NULL) {
    if(regcomp(&compiled, pattern, REG_NOSUB) == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", ch);
    }
    ch = strtok(NULL, " ,");
}
return 0;
```

Comment: you can search for some regex.h tutorial

Comment: @CarlNorum Wouldnt it result in data with also "I.V.R, W.F.B, plan 2," strings ?

Comment: No I wrote the program in Java, I am able to extract the words but as I used C long ago I am not able to do this in C

Comment: @MartinPerry, sure, but that's a solvable problem, right?  Ivan's answer/comments below have the general idea.

Comment: @CarlNorum .. yes :) But just for user1767288 that solution isnt just strtok and some logic must be used as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example program I made up to explain things:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "VRUWFB02=I.V.R, W.F.B, plan 2, VRUWFB01=I.V.R, W.F.B, "
               "plan 1, assa=784617896.9649164, plan24, massmedua=plan12, "
               "masspedia=IVR, masojh, jhsfdkl, oijhojomn, oiafofvj, plan";
    char *p;
    char *q;

    p = strtok(s, " ");
    while (p)
    {
        q = strchr(p, '=');
        if (q)
            printf("%.*s\n", (int)(q - p), p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And output:

```
$ ./example
VRUWFB02
VRUWFB01
assa
massmedua
masspedia
```

The basic idea is to split the string by spaces, then look for `=` characters in the chunks.  If one shows up, print the desired part of that chunk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) function to break a string. You can find an example of using it on the web page I gave reference to.

Comment: I used the Strtok function to break the strings but how can I extract that exact word. I will post the code which I did.

Comment: @user1767288 You can break a string by space symbol ' ' using strtok. Than you can iterate through result strings. If one contains '=' character, you can copy part of this chunk using strcpy function or use strtok again.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but can you give me an idea about the regex used to look for '='

Comment: @user1767288, why use a regular expression at all?

Comment: I thought it would be easy if we use can you suggest anything without the use of regex?